# How to properly write text in MySQL column type varchar(1000)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, varchar

I have a column VARCHAR(1000) in MySQL DB.
So, when PHP requests insert more than 1000 symbols, the rest of the text is rejected.

On the site I had placed a `textarea` with `maxlength=1000`,
but on the server side, PHP parse submitted text with the `htmlspecialchars` function, so if the text was `it's called "nothing"`, it becomes `it's called &quot;nothing&quot;`.

The problem is text could become more than 1000 symbols even it was typed clearly 1000 characters.

Can you help me find the right way, right function etc. to insert all characters which user typed?

Comment: use type text instead of varchar

Comment: Any reason why you use VARCHAR instead of TEXT?

Comment: don't know, but it seems like type VARCHAR more speedy than TEXT

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `htmlspecialchars` when storing in the database. Use it (or `htmlentities`) when retrieving from the DB and writing to the browser.

Comment: Would not that be overkill for server every time call function (like htmlentities) instead ONCE write into the database correct text and then retrieving from the DB without excessive functions?

Comment: It makes the database more general. There's no reason to assume that the data will only be used to display on web pages, you might have other applications that put it in CSV, etc. You should use the functions appropriate to the context, and HTML functions should only be used when creating HTML.

Comment: I see... How about the errors encountered in saving the text in database if the text is not properly escaped? I'm just a beginner so I'm just asking hehe

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri The best way to deal with that is to use prepared statements. If that's not feasible, you use the database's escaping function, e.g. `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @barmar, what I'm currently doing is first filter any text using PHP's FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING and then pass it to mysqli_escape_string(). Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri You should use a prepared statement, so you don't need to do any filtering or escaping.

Comment: @Barmar, okay. Thanks. I have to take your suggestion into consideration. I'll research about prepared statement :)

Comment: @Barmar, I think, the difference of my solution with yours is I'm using `mysqli_escape_string()` while you suggest to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. I'll research about the difference. Thanks again.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry. `mysqli_escape_string()` is an alias of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` ahehehe. So, they're just the same: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php

Comment: @LynnellEmmanuelNeri Yeah, the two names are probably there to parallel the mysql extension. There's a difference between the mysql_XXX versions, the "real" one takes the connection's character set into account.

Answer (score 0):

You must also watch out for UTF-8 which can have characters that take up more space than one byte each.

The idea behind VARCHAR (over CHAR for example) is that it allows the data base to store less bytes to disk when the field is not fully used.

For example, if you write "xx" into VARCHAR(1000), only two characters are stored to your physical data base, not 1000.  (Note, I said characters here not bytes.  The actual number of bytes will be more to allow for wider variable width UTF-8 codes, the needed string length, any word and disk buffer padding, etc.  But clearly you will be storing a lot less bytes than if you used CHAR.)

So let SQL do some of the work for you.  Make the field size 3000 or something, or at least big enough that you will never have a problem, even if a large percentage of the symbols are wider than 8 bits.

Comment: You have some incorrect information, here.  The size of a `VARCHAR` in MySQL is the maximum number of *characters* that can be stored, not the number of bytes.  MySQL understands multibyte characters if the column is declared in a multibyte character set, so there is absolutely no justification for oversizing the column.  Also, there is no "padding," just one or two bytes for storing the length of the data stored in the column.

Comment: I never asserted that the size of VARCHAR was the number of bytes stored as you claim.  But it is related to it, in that if you don't fill your fields full then you save bytes on disk.

Comment: I inferred the assertion from "make the field size 3000 or something" ... and 3000 = 1000 x 3 potential bytes per character in utf-8.  You "will never have a problem" storing 1000 characters in a `VARCHAR(1000)`, even if every character happens to be a 3-byte unicode character.  I assumed you were implying that the size of a varchar is a size in bytes, because I couldn't discern another reason for mentioning "even if a large percentage of the symbols are wider than 8 bits."